# How to debug a javax.validation.constraints.Pattern regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am using javax.validation.constraints.Pattern annotation to validate if the data coming from screen is as per my requirement or not?

My code is as follows:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")
private String regNo;
```

Data should be validated as following sample data.

Correct Test case (below are acceptable values) :

- Test
- Test123
- Test-123
- 123-Test
- 132456
- 15-564
- Test-Sample

But the used regular expression is not accepting following data.

- 132456
- 15-564

Am I using wrong regular expression?

Comment: You have listed `15-564` as both a positive and negative case.  What is your logic here?

Comment: `132456` is both negative and positive case.

Comment: This does not sufficiently explain the logic that the regex should encapsulate. Would you edit the question to add this in?

Comment: Correct test case means these values should accept, not accepting test cases.

I will update the description in simpler terms, sorry description was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have just two cases :

1. (Letters or Digits)-(Letters or Digits)
2. (Letters or Digits)

this regex should works :

```
(\w+-\w+)|(\w+)
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Sorry my description was incorrect. I have updated the description could you please check again.